# If no user found in Get-ADUser script, output a message to my CSV of users found

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got a simple script that works, takes in a list of user Ids and outputs a CSV with their Id, Enabled True / False, and their name. I'm trying to figure out how I can wrap into it a test where if a user is not found based on the Id in the input file, my output will include a "User [Id] is purged." or something similar.

I've been playing around but I'm not sure if I'm going to have to change my output plan to incorporate something like that. Here's what I have working, minus the check for if nothing found, write a message.

```
Get-Content $ENV:USERPROFILE\desktop\testusers.txt | ForEach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Properties SamAccountName,Enabled,Name |
    Select SamAccountName,Enabled,Name
    } | Export-CSV -path $ENV:USERPROFILE\desktop\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to store users `Get-ADUser` cannot find as error in the output csv too.

In that case, simply try to get the user but swallow error messages and use an `if{..} else {..}` construct where in both cases you output objects with the same properties:

```
Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\testusers.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # output the properties you need in the csv
        $user | Select-Object SamAccountName, Enabled, Name
    }
    else {
        # user does not exist; output a similar object with the error
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            SamAccountName = "User '$_' does not exist"
            Enabled        = $null
            Name           = $null
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV -path "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Yup, that's it. I wasn't even thinking of invoking a custom object to hold dummy data for a user not found (I honestly haven't dabbled in PS in maybe ten years?). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will display a warning for those users that could not be found.

Note, `-Properties SamAccountName,Enabled,Name` is not needed in this case, the 3 properties are default properties of the cmdlet.

```
$dom = (Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext

Get-Content $ENV:USERPROFILE\desktop\testusers.txt | ForEach-Object {

    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)){
        continue # go to next iteration if this element is just white space
    }
    
    $usr = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" | Select SamAccountName,Enabled,Name
    
    if(-not $usr){
        Write-Warning "$_ could not be found on $dom"
        continue
    }

    $usr

} | Export-CSV -path $ENV:USERPROFILE\desktop\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```